# nan, floats and ints

Tags: pandas

I'm new to pandas and I have started by trying to read a table completely composed by `1`s and `0`s and I'm using the `read_csv` function to do it. Everything goes OK and I get a DataFrame with int64 as column types. The problem appears when I introduce `NaN` values. In that case I get a DataFrame with column types as `float64`. Is this the expected behaviour? Is the `NaN` value incompatible with the `int` type?

I have also tried to cast the DataFrame with the float column by doing `DataFrame(data, dtype=numpy.int64)`, but in this case I get something like:

```
                    col1   col2
row1 -9223372036854775808      1
row2                    1      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAs / NaN is not supported in integer dtype columns unfortunately (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/gotchas.html#support-for-integer-na). But the second thing you describe is a bug. Creating a GitHub issue about it:

https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/846